# Could not load type 'myinterface' from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies

I have a solution that includes several projects. A few are libs that are building dll's used in my main project in this solution.

My main project builds with output type console application.

This all works fine.

When i change the build output type to a class library (since i want to use this project as a plugin eventually). The project will still build, this time to a dll.

When i use this plugin in an application where i use it as a dll however, it will run up to a certain point where it's trying to load a type defined in an external dll (so NOT built by my solution) and throw the exception:

```
Could not load type 'externalinterface' from assembly 'externallib, version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The dll's are all in the correct folder,etc.

Also worth noting, the plugin is tested in another location than where i built it. The executable still works on this location, the dll/plugin does not. Same amount of dll's in their folders etc.

**EDIT:** I already used ILSpy (dll inspector) to open the actual dll that is being referenced (so externallib in the errormessage) and checked if 'externalinterface' was present and it is.

**EDIT2:** RESOLVED! The program that loaded my plugin was loading the same dll that caused the exception. The dll it loaded was of another version than the one i loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the type `externalinterface` is present in the referred dll.

Comment: It is. I used ILSpy (dll inspector) to open the actual dll that is being referenced (so externallib in the errormessage) and checked if 'externalinterface' was present and it is.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the details of the exception the application is throwing. However, based on the message you gave, it appears your assembly does not have a strong name. If the application attempting to load your assembly as a plugin does have a strong name, then .NET will require all assemblies loaded by it also have a strong name, so you need to configure your assembly to have a strong name before continuing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the assembly loading my assembly does not have a strong name. I know this because i can't actually sign this project because the external dlls are not signed. And the plugin would work with several unsigned dlls while the plugin itself is also unsigned.

Comment: the actual exception : System.Exception: An error occured in Entities.Wrappers.DataProcessing.Wrapper constructor ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'IEngine_R1' from assembly 'ExternalLib, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some supported dll's which is used by the 'externalinterface' is missing in the target machine. In the target machine, check is all the necessary dll's are present in the output folder.

Or blindly copy paste all the dlls in the output folder from the machine where the code is working to the target machine where you have the problem. After this, if the code is working in the target machine, then try to analyze which supporting dll you are missed to copy.

Comment: Like i said. I built the solution as an executable which i ran without a problem on the target location. 

The dll has the exact same amount of dll's as the executable. 

So the supported dll's are on the machine for sure.